# Batch file to build Platform Builder subproject

Tags: platform-builder

[Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/05/07/using-a-batch-file-to-automatically-build-a-windows-ce.aspx) is an example of building the OS with a batch file.  [Here](https://guruce.com/blogpost/commandlinebuild) is another.

I don't want to build the whole kernel, just a subproject contained in the OS project.  Basically the same thing as what "Build all subprojects" does.  (And not make a run-time image after the build.)

What is the command line equivalent of "Build all subprojects"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example I've used with VS2008 / Platform Builder 7.

It looks for subprojects in the specified OSDesign. Any projects found are built with `build -c`.

May need a bit of adjustment depending on the Platform Builder version and what you are looking to achieve, but this is the general idea.

The script leaves behind a `setenv.bat` file. This may be useful for diagnosing build errors, or can simply be deleted.

```
@echo off

set OSDESIGN_NAME=<YourOSDesign>
set BUILD_CONFIG=<Solution Configuration from VS2008, e.g. YourPlatform Release>

set OSDESIGN_DIR=C:\WINCE700\OSDesigns\%OSDESIGN_NAME%\%OSDESIGN_NAME%

rem Set up build environment (equivalent to clicking Build -> "Open Release Directory in Build Window" in VS2008)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Platform Builder\7.00\cepb\IdeVS\pbxmlutils" /getbuildenv /workspace "%OSDESIGN_DIR%\%OSDESIGN_NAME%.pbxml" /config "%BUILD_CONFIG%" > setenv.bat && call setenv.bat

@echo off

rem Ensure any build output is copied to the release directory
set WINCEREL=1

rem Look for subprojects in the OSDesign folder
for /d %%d in (%OSDESIGN_DIR%\*.*) do if exist "%%d\sources" (
    cd %%d
    build -c
)

pause
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.  It is enough to modify the OS batch build: Replace "blddemo clean -q" with "set WINCEREL=1, cd <subprojFolder>, build -c"